# How can I accept keystrokes in a WinForms app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keyevent

How do I accept keystrokes? For example, I want to quit the application if the user presses <kbd>q</kbd>.

How do I go about doing this? I am using WinForms.

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, .... ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to implement keyboard shortcuts in winforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-winforms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) or [`KeyUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx) events if you are using `WinForms`.

For example, just drop the following code into your form class to override the `OnKeyUp` event and close whenever the user presses the <kbd>q</kbd> key:

```
protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Q)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    base.OnKeyUp(e);
}
```

Comment: do i necessarily have to deal with events?? the only thing i intend to do is exit when the user presses a certain key.

Comment: @user: Yes, you have to deal with events. *Everything* you do in WinForms will deal with events. Windows is an event-driven environment. Not sure why you'd prefer to avoid events in the first place, but the code to do this isn't complicated.

Comment: How did you get the nice 'Q' key?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of application you are making?
Window Forms? WPF? Console?
 In the first two there are events related to key presses, in the third one, you can use Console.Read or ReadLine methods and test the return value

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use KeyPreview and OnKeyPreview here, depending on what controls are you using on the form.  Sometimes, KeyDown and KeyUp will be handled before you get a chance to handle them yourself.

BTW, for windows apps, using 'q' key without any modifiers to quit isn't such a great idea, since you might have textboxes on the form that accept input, and your app will quit if someone writes 'quebec' into the textbox.

And if you don't want to use events, then OVERRIDE same virtual methods and provide implementation for them that will do what you want.  But again, preferred method here is with events.

Comment: Why do you say that the preferred way to do this is by handling events, rather than overriding the appropriate methods? A control really shouldn't ever handle its own events. That violates most of the rules of object-oriented design, and can wreak all sorts of havoc and unexpected behavior if someone later decides to subclass that control.

Comment: I was talking about FORMS, not controls, since the question is (probably) concerning creating a form that will close.