# C# capture main form keyboard events

Tags: c#, winforms

How to catch keyboard events of the WinForm main form, where other controls are.
So I want to catch one event <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and doesn't matter where focus is.
But without Pinvoke (hooks and such ...)
Only .NET managed internal power.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to implement keyboard shortcuts in winforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-winforms)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code. Use the interface `IMessageFilter` you can filter any <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+key.

```
public partial class Form1 : 
    Form,
    IMessageFilter
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosed);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        //here you can specify  which key you need to filter

        if (m.Msg == 0x0100 && (Keys)m.WParam.ToInt32() == Keys.S &&
            ModifierKeys == Keys.Control) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this and worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

the [Form Class (System.Windows.Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) has [OnKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeydown.aspx), [OnKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeypress.aspx), and [OnKeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeyup.aspx) event methods that you can use to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

use the [KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx) in those methods to determine which keys were pressed

EDIT

be sure to enable `Form.KeyPreview = true;` so the form will capture the events regardless of focus.

Comment: You missed the "doesn't matter where focus is" requirement.

Comment: Did you read: 
"So I want to catch one event Ctrl + S and doesn't matter where focus is".
Please, read carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `KeyDown` on the form and all its controls.

```
private void OnFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        control.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
    }
}

private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue == (int)Keys.S)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ctrl + s");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read: "So I want to catch one event Ctrl + S and doesn't matter where focus is". Please, read carefully.

Comment: @Robb: Yes I read that, but I assumed that the phase `doesn't matter where focus is` referring to the inside the form or its controls so no matter if the focus where on for example a `textBox1` or in the form. isn't that you meant?

Comment: @Robb: did you notice the question on my previous comment?

Comment: Jalal, yas I meant that... but if this question is only about KeyDown event, then I wouldn't ask. I used to apply P/Invoke Keyboard hook Proc before, and Asish's answer was exectly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You may add a MenuStrip and then create a menu strip item named save and give it a short cut Ctrl + S. Add a event handler for that. This will fire even if the focus is on other control on the form. If you don't like to see the MenuStrip; you can set visible = false too. I must admit this is ugly.