# Is any way to check or uncheck the WinForm checkbox with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: winforms

I need to set Keyboard Shortcut in WinForm checkbox. For check or uncheck.

I don't know the possibility of this,.

But With the Help of arrow keys and Space Key it can be done.

My requirement is like Below,..

```
Alt + C - Checked
Alt + U - Un checked.
```

Is Any Possibilities is there?.

Comment: You should not do this using the Alt key. That's reserved for keyboard mnemonics.

Comment: Ok Friend. I use c and u buttons only. And Another Thing what is  mnemonics ?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to implement keyboard shortcuts in winforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-winforms)

Comment: Having keyboard focus checkbox can be checked by pressing space bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually check for the required key combination in form keydown like this (Assuming C#):- 
you should try some other key combination because of reserved keyboard mnemonics as  Cody Gray mentioned.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // When the user presses both the 'Alt' key and 'C' key,
    if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "C")
    {

        //check the checkbox
        this.checkBox1.Checked= true;

    } 

    // When the user presses both the 'Alt' key and 'U' key,
    if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "U")
    {

        //Uncheck the checkbox
        this.checkBox1.Checked= false;

    } 
}
```

Check [Form.KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property to get or set a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

Comment: This event Not Fire in my Project. Is any Propriety to be Set?. or Missed anything. Thanks.

Comment: + 1 for quick Answer and Its make the Answer Correctly.

Comment: Oh i find out the Propriety Named Key Preview.

Comment: You may try Form's KeyPress  event also.. Oh great , let me edit my answer..!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with mnemonics...(if you don't mind including the key you want to use for the shortcut within the text of the checkbox).

- Make sure UseMnemonic is set to true on your checkBox (I think this is the default)
- Put the key you want to use in the text of the checkbox prefixed with an ampersand (e.g., &Check)

...then the key will be shown underlined in the text when the alt key is pressed & pressing the mnemonic key will alternatively check & uncheck the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by overriding the `processCmdKey` of the form control. You can set up all your shortcuts this way. Check the following code below (VB.NET):

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.N Then
         ''call a method that check or uncheck the control
    End If 
   ''you can even combine modifiers keys
    If keyData =keys.Control + Keys.T Then
        ''do something
    End If

    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```