# Cycling through TabControl tabs while not having focus on it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I started with my first WinForms project, and bumped into a small problem on the way.

I have a Form with a TabControl and some buttons outside it.
The problem is when i have a button focused and press Ctrl-Tab - nothing happens. But if you open, for instance, properties window of a file in explorer, you can cycle through tabs using Ctrl-Tab no matter which element has the focus.

So what is the *right* way to make such behavior? I mean, i can do `Form.KeyPreview = true` and write handlers myself, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to implement keyboard shortcuts in winforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-winforms)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the correct way is the one you mentioned yourself i.e. set `Form.KeyPreview = true` and write private `Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)` handler to switch tabs.