# Get all keys that are pressed

Tags: c#, keypress, keydown

What do I have to use to be able to get "all keys" that are pressed on the keyboard at the moment? Since `Form.KeyPress += new EventHandler()` doesn't do much at all when it's filled of controls. It doesn't call it no matter what I do, neither KeyDown, KeyUp or anything else... and yeah, I know how to use them.

So, if there's any function in the system that can check for pressed keys, that returns an array of the keys used or something - I would be grateful to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Do you want all keys pressed when you run a specific piece of code, or do you want an event that happens whenever a key is pressed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to implement keyboard shortcuts in winforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-winforms)

Comment: Say I want to have an eventhandler for MouseWheel, but I want the "Ctrl" key to be pressed when I execute something in the EventHandler. so If I scroll the wheel I only get the results of the mousewheel, not the keypress.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It sounds like you want to query the state of all keys in the keyboard.  The best function for that is the Win32 API call `GetKeyboardState`

- [GetKeyboardState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I don't believe there is a good managed equivalent of that function.  The PInvoke code for it is fairly straight forward

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte [] lpKeyState);

var array = new byte[256];
GetKeyboardState(array);
```

This will populate the `byte[]` with the up / down state of every virtual key in the system.  If the high bit is set then the virtual key is currently pressed.  Mapping a `Key` to a virtual key code is done by only considering the `byte` portion of the numeric `Key` value.

```
public static byte GetVirtualKeyCode(Key key) {
  int value = (int)key;
  return (byte)(value & 0xFF);
}
```

The above works for most of the `Key` values but you need to be careful with modifier keys. The values `Keys.Alt`, `Keys.Control` and `Keys.Shift` won't work here because they're technically modifiers and not key values.  To use modifiers you need to use the actual associated key values `Keys.ControlKey`, `Keys.LShiftKey`, etc ... (really anything that ends with Key)

So checking if a particular key is set can be done as follows

```
var code = GetVirtualKeyCode(Key.A);
if ((array[code] & 0x80) != 0) {
  // It's pressed
} else { 
  // It's not pressed
}
```

Comment: It works for the modifier keys as well, you however have to use Keys.AltKey, ShiftKey and ControlKey.

Comment: Yeah... But one who hasn't used those things before it might be good to include what namespaces I need, why DllImport shows red, why GetKeyboardState isn't nowhere to be found, etc, etc... Half baked answers means I have to search more for answers equals no answer.

Comment: @Deukalion `DllImport` is a common enough type that I didn't feel the need to include a namespace espc since the IDE will just include it for you if you select the namespace in the auto-correct drop down. Also `GetKeyboardState` isn't a .Net function.  It's a native one I imported, if you paste in my definition it should work fine.

Comment: What is 0x80 and why's it there?

Comment: this can be confusing in winform and hook.
I see they all exist Key. does your solution work in both?

Answer (score 6):

I've expanded on JaredPar's answer a little bit. The following method returns the collection of all keys that are currently being pressed:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Input;

private static readonly byte[] DistinctVirtualKeys = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 256)
    .Select(KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey)
    .Where(item => item != Key.None)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(item => (byte)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(item))
    .ToArray();

/// <summary>
/// Gets all keys that are currently in the down state.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// A collection of all keys that are currently in the down state.
/// </returns>
public IEnumerable<Key> GetDownKeys()
{
    var keyboardState = new byte[256];
    GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);

    var downKeys = new List<Key>();
    for (var index = 0; index < DistinctVirtualKeys.Length; index++)
    {
        var virtualKey = DistinctVirtualKeys[index];
        if ((keyboardState[virtualKey] & 0x80) != 0)
        {
            downKeys.Add(KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey(virtualKey));
        }
    }

    return downKeys;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] keyState);
```

Comment: I'm haviong an hard time translating the `DistinctVirtualKeys` assignation in VB.Net. Can you comment it better and also i get error that there is no parameter for `.Select(KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey)` ?

Comment: Add a reference to WindowsBase. There you find the `enum System.Windows.Input.Key` [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to know all keystrokes when your application is active, regardless which control within your application has the focus, than you can use the [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property of your form.

Simply set the property to true and subscribe to the desired Key events **on the form**. Now you'll receive all keystrokes within your application before they are forwarded to the concrete control, allowing you to react on yourself on it and cancel its forwarding to the control be setting the `Cancel` property to true.

If you need to receive the pressed keys while your application is not the active one, then you need some kind of low-level keyboard hook. I didn't test it, but [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) looks quite promising for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [PreviewKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx) event which will fire if a key is pressed while the form has focus, even if another child control within that form currently has focus.