# Problems with KeyDown, doesn't work

Tags: c#, keypress, keydown, keyup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to implement keyboard shortcuts in winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-winforms)

I have a probleme with KeyDown or KeyPress or KeyUp. I creat a new KeyDown for the form (`private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)`) where I insert this code:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
                MessageBox.Show("yes");
```

If you pess Ctrl + A will show you a MessageBox with Yes message.

The probleme is this: if I create a new project (`Windows form application`) will work perfectly, but if I add the code in my Windows form application (have like 4201 code lines) will not work, and I don't know what is the issues. I don't know what are the issues in this case.

Maybe is becouse the librarys:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Media;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
```

Or the code that I add in Program.cs for let the people start only once time the app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace Programari
{
    static class Program
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            bool createdNew = true;
            using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyApplicationName", out createdNew))
            {
                if (createdNew)
                {
                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                    Application.Run(new Form1());
                }
                else
                {
                    Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

                    if(Settings1.Default.rosaueng == 0)
                        MessageBox.Show("smartAppointment este deja deschis, ii gasesti iconita in System Icons !","EROARE DESCHIDERE APLICATIE");
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("smartAppointment is already open, you can find him at System Icons !", "ERROR OPEN APPLICATION");

                    foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName))
                    {
                        if (process.Id != current.Id)
                        {
                            SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you know, please tell me. Thanks !

Comment: Only the window with the focus gets the KeyDown event.  Which will never be form if it has any focusable controls.  Override ProcessCmdKey instead.

Comment: why not just have keypreview = true and then handle keydown?

Comment: This is not a duplicate--it just suffers from poor wording. Seems like a copy/paste problem and an event handler that is too vague to be useful for key detection.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is exactly as you have it written above, the problem is that you are typing the event args in your handler to `EventArgs` instead of the more specific `KeyEventArgs`. `EventArgs` does not have a `KeyCode` property. Again, if what you pasted above is what you have, your issue is likely that you can't compile, and this is the reason why.

**UPDATE**

Here's what the proper method signature would look like for handling `KeyDown`:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I copied badly, was `private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e)` . Why can't compile, the app work perfecly in rest !

Comment: If you can't compile, the problem is exactly as I have said. You need to use a `KeyEventHandler` and your method signature should read `private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)`.

Comment: In this case I try, but don't work ! I resolve the problem with the KeyDown, but how I can make that if I press Ctr+N, will work even if the app is close in System Icons ?

Answer (score 0):

I try the method that Hans Passant told me and work perfectly.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.N))
            {
                //button5_Click(this, new EventArgs());
                MessageBox.Show("da");
                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

But I try to run the button5 when I will press Ctrl+N and the code `button5_Click(this, new EventArgs());`, don't work. How I can call the button5_Click function ?

Comment: `button5_Click(this, null);` will work perfectly, sorry for the question, but now I have another question. I user Form_Closing, after I press X, whe app will go in System Icons, but how I can do that if i press Ctrl+N to call the function if the app is in System Icons ?

Comment: Hey, I'm glad you got past your initial hurdle. But to keep things clean and organized, you should probably open separate questions for your other inquiries. Keep things easier to understand.