# how to link/set the ENTER to a function in winforms without relation to a Textbox control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using Winforms.

I've a screen approx. 10 fields. and a Update button.
But I don't want to use neither show on screen a button (`btnUpdate`).

I just want to show the the fields, they can change some values and by pressing the enter it should execute a function in code behind.

I googled and find some solutions like `KeyPress` on `TextBox` or whatever, but I don't want to link this to a `TextBox`. Then I found `form.Acceptbutton = btnUpdate`... but then I have to use a button on my designer.

so how can I make a situtation by not USING a Button control to do an update (in other words executing function in code-behind by pressing the Enter Key).

Comment: Take a look in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application

Comment: Do you have an adversion to making the button not visible and using it in that sense?  If not, you would have to create a button programmatically, but never add it to then controls of the form and then link to the acceptbutton property.  I have never done this my self, so I could be wrong...

Comment: Well, you know that you are supposed to press Enter.  Exactly how would a regular user discover this?  He'll just click the Close button in despair.  Create usable UI, an OK button is boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the ProcessCmdKey

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Return)
    {
        //Raise Update Event
        return true;
    }
    else if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        //Raise Cancel Event
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```