# Adding a shortcut to a button in Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I add a shortcut to a certain button in windows forms application?

For an instance I want to assign the combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to my exit button, so when I press it, the code in that particular button executes.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application

Answer (score 6):

Write an ampersand ("`&`") in the [`Text` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.text.aspx) of the button before a character to have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*that key*</kbd> as the shortcut.

E.g.:

```
myButton.Text = "Press &me";
```

would make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> the shortcut.

Beware of duplicates and ensure you only assign a shortcut once per form. You can also assign shortcuts to e.g. [`Label` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx) to make the control next to the label (in the tab order) get the focus, e.g. a text box control.

If you want to have <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd> take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application), as [Plue commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457687/adding-a-shortcut-to-a-button-in-windows-forms-ap/21457747#comment32380519_21457687). Be aware that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*some key*</kbd> is the usual way, so better have a good reason to change the default behavior.

Comment: and if i want to make it ctrl + m?

Comment: Then, take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application), as [Plue commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457687/adding-a-shortcut-to-a-button-in-windows-forms-ap/21457747#comment32380519_21457687). Be aware that `Alt`+`some key` is the usual way, so better have a good reason to change the default behavior.

Comment: Wrong link for **this SO question**