# How to call the Click Event of user control from form, when User control has a label set to dock fill in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a user control with a label set as Dock Fill.
I have created the Click event of the User control as well as of the label:

```
 private void Cell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ClickCount == 0)
            {
                this.ClickCount = 1;
                this.SetSeat_Male();
            }
            else if (this.ClickCount == 1)
            {
                this.ClickCount = 2;
                this.SetSeat_Female();
            }
            else if (this.ClickCount == 2)
            {
                this.ClickCount = 0;
                this.SetSeat_Empty();
            }
        }
        private void lblSeatNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cell_Click(sender, e);
        }
```

I am using this user control on another form, but the click event of this user control on form is not calling the click event of the cell in this user control.
How can i call this click event on my form?

Comment: you should change Cell_Click to be a normal subroutine, instead of a event handler, so change to, private void Cell_Click() {..}

Comment: @JoeWu can you please explain?

Comment: the click event is handled by 'lblSeatNo_Click' already, it is not necessary to call what seems to be another handler ( actually delete Cell_click method, and place its content directly inside 'lblSeatNo_Click'

Comment: but then i need to make this label public (so that i can access its event in the form where i use this control)???

Comment: i see your point, make sure to set parent form's 'keypreview' property to 'true'. please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782753/how-to-get-all-keypress-events-as-a-usercontrol-in-c

Comment: i am not handling key press event.. i am trying to handle Mouse-Click and Click Event to supprot Touch-Screen as well.