# How to make keyboard shortcuts to button click

Tags: c#, button, onkeypress

I am doing my graduation work and I need a little help.
So far I've done most of my work and now I need someone to help me with the shortcuts.

This is how my work looks like (for now):
[image]

I need to make shortcuts for those buttons so that user doesn't have to click on button with mouse. I wish to make it possible that when user presses F1 on the keybord - it's like he pressed button1 with mouse. F2 stands for button2 and so on.
Shortcuts as CTRL+ some key are also acceptable. I only need example how to make couple buttons, and i will make others :)
Thanks

Comment: you should look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application

Answer (score 1):

Set Form1's `KeyPreview`-property to `true` in the designer or in the code:

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

Then add `KeyUp`-action to your form, which accepts all keys (even `Delete` etc):

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
   {
      button1ClickMethod();
   }
}
```

Then separate your buttons' actions to individual methods, like `button1ClickMethod()`, and avoid using the `Button1_Click(null, null);`. Call this `button1ClickMethod()` in the `KeyUp`-event when a desired key is up.

To use combinations, you can use this:

```
// If CTRL and F1 were pressed
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Shortcut CTRL + F1 was pressed!");
}
```

You can also check if the `Shift` was pressed at the same time with `e.Shift`-property, same way like the `e.Control`.

Answer (score -1):

KeyPress event will help you

Sample code ;

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //Call the event according to key
        // if(e.KeyChar == "")
        //btnSave_Click(null,null)
    }
```