# When using read-only textbox, some keyboard combinations get handled differently

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, keydown

It seems as though <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (at the very least) don't get handled in the same way as other keyboard combinations. The <kbd>E</kbd> and the <kbd>R</kbd> respectively aren't recognized.

The way I've been testing this is to create a form with a TextBox and Button, then add the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.ReadOnly = !textBox1.ReadOnly;
}

private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    bool ctrl = ModifierKeys == Keys.Control;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Control pressed: " + e.Control + "    Key pressed: " + e.KeyData + "       Modifier Control pressed: " + ctrl);
}
```

When the TextBox is ReadOnly, only certain key combinations don't work. I added a context menu strip with an item for handling the desired keyboard combinations, but that interferes with the textbox's context menu (actually the DevEx spellchecker context menu I have associated with the TextBox)--it doesn't even display.

Does anyone know why or the best way to get around this? Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Try using ProcessCmdKey() instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application/400325#400325
  By the way, what are Ctrl+E and Ctrl+R supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ended up overriding ProcessCmdKey in my DevEx MemoEdit.

Comment: Glad to help. If I post it as an answer do you give me brownie-points? :-)

Comment: @RenniePet: Absolutely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the legendary Hans Passant points out on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application/400325#400325), it is usually best to handle Ctrl+x keystrokes that are intended to provide a command-like function by using a [ProcessCmdKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx) method.

Glad it worked out for you.