# Parent window shortcut steals input from modeless child

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modeless

I have an application with a parent window and the potential for multiple modeless windows to be pulled up from it.

In one of these modeless windows, there is a text box.

When typing in the textbox, I want to be able to hit CTRL+A to select all text.

However, my parent window has a menu item that specifies CTRL+A as its shortcut (it does it's own select-all sort of thing).

In the KeyDown event in my modeless textbox/control/form, I never see CTRL+A come through.  In short, it is being stolen by the parent window.  I want to override it to do something different in the modeless window. Alternatively, I want to override it to do nothing at all. If possible, how do I do this?

Comment: Is this a WinForms application?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: why don't you alter the code / functionality to make the forms popup as modal.. is there a reason for not doing so ..otherwise you could create some delegate event handlers ..just a thought..

Comment: @JohnSaunders yes, this is WinForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer here: 
[Best way to implement keyboard shortcuts in a Windows Forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application)

The trick is to override the ProcessCmdKey method and return true when you pick up on the desired input (Ctrl + A) in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 (Quick & Dirty):
In WinForm or WPF, create an eventlistener for keydown.
In the code-behind

```
private void textBox1_keyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control & e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        textBox1.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Option 2:
Inherit a textbox and override OnPreviewKeyDown