# Shortcut in Visual Studio - Windows Form Application while other Window is active

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, shortcut

I want to use a Shortcut in a Windows Form App and found the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application).

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
     if (keyData == (Keys.Enter)) {
       MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
       return true;
     }
     return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
   }
```

But this only works, if the window is active. How can I use the shortcut even if a different window is active?

Comment: Of the top of my head you could use inheritance and intercept the window messages in a base form and extend from base form.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single entry point for message catching and dispatching in a base form.

**Base Form**

```
public class BaseForm : Form
{
    public void MyMessage(hwnd:HWND)
    {
       ...
       case MSG_SPECIFIC_ACTION_1 : handled=this.DoOnSpecificAction1();
       ... 
    }

    protected bool DoOnSpecificAction1(){ return=false;}
}
```

**Base Form Descendant**

```
public class MyCustomForm : BaseForm
{
    protected override bool DoOnSpecificAction1()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        return true;    
    }
}
```

**Edit - Global KeyboardHook**

If you are looking to trap all key events in other applications then you will need to use a Keyboard Hook. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14485/Low-level-Windows-API-hooks-from-C-to-stop-unwante) is a nice article describing using `SetWindowsHookEx`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't understand it yet. But I will try it this afternoon and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I don't understand why I need a Visual Inheritance. The active window would not be a different Windows Forms App but a CAD-software. I want to show different information on my second screen while working on a 3D model. I hope this makes it more clear :-S

Comment: For example in TS3 I can set shortcuts and use those even if I'm in a game.

Comment: Let me understand. Is the other window is in a separate application?

Comment: Yes exactly. That's my problem