# Copying excel data to a windows form using ctrl+c & v

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to make a 1 column data grid in a windows form where I can copy paste data from an excel sheet.

I am able to create the data grid using visual studio but ctrl+c &V is not working while copying data from excel sheet.

-Sa

Comment: Of course CTRL+C and CTRL+V is not going to work. You need to define event handlers for that. The DataGrid is not going to do this for you automagically.

Answer (score 1):

1. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application) to implement <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcut.
2. Use

   ```
   string txt = Clipboard.GetText();
   ```

   to get the text from the Clipboard.
3. Excel will provide tab-separated values for each cell in the row, while rows are separated by \r\n. Insert it into your grid as you like.