# C# richTextBox filter out or remap a keystroke

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Using C#, in a Win form, what's the simplest way to filter out (or remap) a keystroke (Ctrl-Shift-Z) in a richTextBox? I know of various keyboard hook projects on CodeProject, but they involve entire classes. I'd like to use the simplest method possible, such as one function override. The reason: richTextBox seems to treat Ctrl-Shift-Z the same way as Ctrl-Z i.e. as Undo. I'd prefer to use Ctrl-Shift-Z as Redo. I tried the "KeyDown" method, but it doesn't seem to capture the keystroke, keystrokes seem to be handled lower than that.

```
private void richTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Z && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control) {
        richTextBox.Redo();
    }
}
```

Comment: WinForm (I'll edit the original)

Comment: I don't want to disable shortcuts, I just want Ctrl-Shift-Z to work like Ctrl-Y (Redo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
  if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.Z)) {
    richTextBox.Redo();
    return true;
  }
  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

As [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application) said in his answer, you should also check to make sure you have the form's [KeyPreview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property to True.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

In your parent form, set the KeyPreview property to true and then look for the desired shortcut in the Form's KeyDown event.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += MyForm_KeyDown;
    }

    private void MyForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Modifiers & Keys.Shift) != 0 &&
            (e.Modifiers & Keys.Control) != 0 &&
            (e.KeyCode == Keys.Z))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            richTextBox1.Redo();
        }
    }
}
```