# Return To Default Values

Tags: c#, winforms

- 1

I have this small code that when mouse over on a label it should change the font size etc....

```
        private void label1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Font = new Font("arial",18, FontStyle.Bold,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
```

so it's work , but i want to return the default value to this label when i move the mouse again

- 2

how to make the button have default key that when i press it the button will do it's work ?

do any one have course about events ?

Comment: Set the default properties back to your label in the `MouseLeave` event.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Questions asking for tutorials or courses are off-topic.

Comment: What's mean that default value? Do you want label Text when clicked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to implement keyboard shortcuts in a Windows Forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Comment: @MetehanSenol like i have the  default font size of this lab is 18 and when mouse over it's change to 20 but when i move the mouse again i need to return it to the default value ( 18 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use MouseEnter and MouseLeave event.

In MouseEnter set your "hover"-font.
In MouseLeave reset to default font.

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = "Hello World!";
label.MouseEnter += label_MouseEnter;
label.MouseLeave += label_MouseLeave;
```

Example changes from Segoe UI 12 to 18 pixel

```
private void label_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = sender as Label;

    if(label != null)
    {
        label.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 12, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
}
private void label_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = sender as Label;

    if (label != null)
    {
        label.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 18, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at my changes

Comment: thanks alot it's work for me too , i found that i can use mouse hover and mouse leave events but thanks any way

Comment: You should use MouseEnter, because MouseHover fires multiple times, while moving Mouse over Control. MouseEnter only once.

Comment: @chistian edel you mean every  time the mouse over on label it's going to do code ?

Comment: Yes, MouseHover is described as follows: Occurs when the mouse pointer rests on the control.

Answer (score 0):

- 1 Use [Control.MouseLeave event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave(v=vs.100).aspx) and in there [Control.ResetFont() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resetfont(v=vs.100).aspx)

  private void label1_MouseLeave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
      label1.ResetFont();
  }